# verifying multiple form criteria are met

Tags: jquery, forms

I am attempting to run specific lines of code (currently only listed as alert messages but later will be replaced with json requests) when multiple form criteria are all met - specifically any radio button and one specific select option selected (each select option will have a different request to make and very unique code) - unfortunately I can not figure out for the life of me how to get this to work - I have attempted to just do onclick events to call a function and run pretty dirty looking if statements but this doesn't work (and lets be honest even if it did - it certainly isn't meeting any standards)  How do I make this work?

```
<input type='radio' name='emp' onclick='changeselected()' value='1'>
<input type='radio' name='emp' onclick='changeselected()' value='2'>
<input type='radio' name='emp' onclick='changeselected()' value='3'>

<select id='umodt' name='umodt' disabled>
      <option value=' '></option>
      <option onclick='changeselected()' value='View'>View Employee</option>
      <option onclick='changeselected()' value='Add'>Add Report</option>
</select>


            <script type="text/javascript">
function changeselected(){
if($('#emp').is(':checked')) {
    if ($("#umodt").val() == "View") {
        alert("view selected");
    }
    if ($("#umodt").val() == "Add") {
        alert("add selected");
    }
}

}
</script>
```

Comment: that disable is removed by other code that is not visible here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"#emp" does not select elements with the name "emp".

"#emp" selects the first element with the id of "emp"

Either give each checkbox an unique id, or use a class.

Then change your function to use 'this' as a selector.

Something like:

```
function changeselected(){
if($(this).is(':checked')) {
    if ($("#umodt").val() == "View") {
        alert("view selected");
    }
    if ($("#umodt").val() == "Add") {
        alert("add selected");
    }
}

}
```

Also, ditch the onclicks on your select list options. Use onChange or onClick on the actual list.

Comment: Since you have harcoded the event handler to the checkbox, you can avoid using classes/names/ids all together. Just use the this selector.

Comment: it needs to be able to fire whether the select option is changed or the radiobutton which is why I selected to do an external function

Comment: then add an onchange event to the select list. Not a onclick.

Comment: just as easily I added a class to the radio buttons - changed the select to onchange and changed the selector to $(".emp") and I have a working solution - thank you

Comment: Yeah, but your logic is flawed now. If any of the checkboxes are checked, your first condition will return true.

Comment: thats the intent - I just want to verify Any radio button is selected - ie field not empty

Answer (score 1):

There can only be one ID element on each page. You should create a variable that references each radio button and then iterate through them with the `each` method. You can then use the `prop` method to set the `selected` attribute.

```
function changeselected(){
    var radio = $("input[type=radio]");
    radio.each(function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            var value = $(this).prop("value");
            $("option[value=" + value + "]").prop("selected", "selected");
        }
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kwz0ufq9/1/